# Was Hanuman ever shot in the leg by an arrow?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, lakshmana

Was Hanuman ever shot in the leg by an arrow while he was flying with the mountain containing the Sanjivani herb, for Lakshmana?

I've heard that he was, which was a reminder for him to be humble and not proud because he was thinking how much Lord Rama needed him!

[image]

Comment: I have heard story about Bharata hitting hanuman when he is bringing the mountain of sanjeevni herb for lakshman.

Answer (score 6):

In Lanka Kanda of [Ramcharitmanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramcharitmanas), Bharata hits Hanuman with an arrow thinking he's a demon:

> दो० - देखा भरत बिसाल अति निसिचर मन अनुमानि। 
>   बिनु फर सायक मारेउ चाप श्रवन लगि तानि। ५८ ॥
>
> DO.: dekha bharata bisala ati nisicara mana anumani, 
>   binu phara sāyaka māreu cāpa śravana lagi tāni.58.
>
> **Bharata** (who kept vigil at night ever since his return from Citrakuta) espied a colossal figure coursing through the air and **thinking it to be some demon** drew his bow to the ear and **struck him with a headless shaft**. (58)

Bharata regrets his decision for shooting down Hanuman and prays that he recover quickly:

> चौ० - परेउ मुरुछि महि लागत सायक। सुमिरत राम राम रघुनायक। 
>   सुनि प्रिय बचन भरत तब धाए। कपि समीप अति आतुर आए। १ ॥ 
>   बिकल बिलोकि कीस उर लावा । जागत नहिं बहु भाँति जगावा। 
>   मुख मलीन मन भए दुखारी। कहत बचन भरि लोचन बारी ॥ २॥ 
>   जेहिं बिधि राम बिमुख मोहि कीन्हा। तेहिं पुनि यह दारुन दुख दीन्हा। 
>   जों मोरें मन बच अरु काया । प्रीति राम पद कमल अमाया। ३ ।। 
>   ती कपि होउ बिगत श्रम सूला। जों मो पर रघुपति अनुकूला। 
>   सुनत बचन उठि बैठ कपीसा। कहि जय जयति कोसलाधीसा ॥ ४॥
>
> Cau.: pareu muruchi mahi lāgata sāyaka, sumirata rāma rāma raghunāyaka. 
>   suni priya bacana bharata taba dhāe, kapi samīpa ati ātura āe.1. 
>   bikala biloki kisa ura lāvā, jāgata nahř bahu bhãti jagāvā. 
>   mukha malina mana bhae dukhari, kahata bacana bhari locana bãrI.2. 
>   jehŤ bidhi rāma bimukha mohi kīnhā, tehi puni yaha daruna dukha dinha. 
>   jaui moré mana baca aru kaya, priti rama pada kamala amaya.3. 
>   tau kapi hou bigata śrama sūlā, jaŭ mo para raghupati anukūlā. 
>   sunata bacana uthi baitha kaplīsā, kahi jaya jayati kosaladhisa.4.
>
> Struck by the dart, Hanuman dropped unconscious to the ground, crying "Rama, Rama, O Lord of the Raghus!" The moment Bharata heard these pleasing words he rushed and came post-haste by the side of the monkey. Seeing the monkey in swoon, the prince clasped him to his bosom and tried every means to bring him back to consciousness but in Vain. With a sad look in his face and much distressed at heart and his eyes full of tears, he spoke the following Words; "The selfsame Providence who alienated me from Sri Rama has also inflicted this terrible suffering on me. If in thought, word and deed cherish sincere devotion to Sri Rama's lotus feet, and **if the Lord of the Raghus is kindly disposed towards me, may this monkey be relieved of all exhaustion and pain**." As soon as these words entered his ears the monkey chief arose and sat up, crying "Glory, all glory to the Lord of Kosala!" (1-4)

Wikipedia also [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramcharitmanas#La.E1.B9.85k.C4.81_K.C4.81.E1.B9.87.E1.B8.8D):

> Hanuman makes good speed towards Lanka when suddenly he is shot by an
>   arrow as he approaches Nandigram. Hanuman is mistaken to be a demon by
>   Bharat. Hanuman falls to the ground together with the great hill.
>   Hanuman regains consciousness and recognizes that Bharata is Rama's
>   brother.

There is no scriptural mention of any reminder to Hanuman that he is feeling proud of his strength.

But Hanuman did feel proud when Bharata told him that he can take his arrow to go fast to Lanka where his brother Lakshmana needs him.

> चौ०-ताप्त कुसल कहु सुखनिधान की। सहित अनुज अरु मातु जानकी ॥ 
>   कपि सब चरित समास बखाने। भए दुखी मन महुँ पछिताने ॥ १ ॥ 
>   अहह दैव मैं कत जग जायऊँ । प्रभु के एकह काज न आयऊँ ॥ 
>   जानि कुअवसरु मन धरि धीरा। पुनि कपि सन बोले बलबीरा। ॥ २॥  
>   तात गहरु होइहि तोहि जाता। काजु नसाइहि होत प्रभाता ॥  
>   चढ़ मम सायक सैल समेता। पठवीं तोहि जहँ कृपानिकेता ॥ ३ ॥  
>   **सुनि कपि मन उपजा अभिमाना। मोरें भार चलिहि किमि बाना ॥**  
>   राम प्रभाव बिचारि बहोरी । बंदि चरन कह कपि कर जोरी ॥ ४ ॥
>
> Cau.: tāta kusala kahu sukhanidhāna kī, sahita anuja aru mātu jānakī. 
>   kapi saba carita samasa bakhane, bhae dukhi mana mahu pachitane.1.  
>   ahaha daiva mai kata jaga jayau, prabhu ke ekahu kaja na ayau.  
>   jani kuavasaru mana dhari dhira, puni kapi sana bole balabira.2.  
>   tāta gaharu hoihi tohi jātā, kāju nasāihi hota prabhātā.  
>   caRhu mama sāyaka saila sametā, pațhavaŭ tohi jahă krpāniketā.3.  
>   **suni kapi mana upajā abhimānā, morē bhāra calihi kimi bānā.**  
>   rāma prabhāva bicāri bahorī, barindi carana kaha kapi kara jorī.4.
>
> "Tell me, dear friend, if all is well with Sri Rama, the Fountain of Joy, as well as With His younger brother (Laksmana) and mother Janaki (Janaka's Daughter)." The monkey chief told him in brief all that had happened and Bharata felt much distressed to hear it and his heart was filled with remorse. "Ah me, good heavens, why should I have been born into this World at all, if I could not be of any service to the Lord?" But realizing the adverse circumstances, the gallant and mighty prince recollected himself and addressed Hanuman again, "You will be delayed in your journey and nothing will avail after daybreak. Therefore, ascend my arrow, mountain and all, and I will send you straight into the presence of the All-merciful." **Hanuman's pride was tickled** when he heard these words. "**How will the arrow fly with my weight?**" he thought. Then, recalling Sri Rama's glory, he bowed at Bharata's feet and spoke with joined palms:- (1-4)

In the above quote it is written that, there was vanity (negative pride) feeling in Hanuman's mind that how can an arrow carry his weight.

---

Google Drive link to free copy of Gita Press' Ramcharitamanas (English):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T0zBCVuV7cR055dEFfNFRNQ28/view?usp=sharing